# How to edit read only file, as root without sudo

Tags: ssh, permissions, vi, sudo

I have a thecus home server, I'd like to edit the index.php file located under `/img/www/htdocs/index.php` however it tells me every time I `vi` that it's 'Read-only'.

I checked it's file permissions using `ls -l index.php`:

`-rw-r--r--     1 root    root    7619 Mar 29    2013 /img/www/htdocs/index.php`

From my understanding, the `-rw` first in the permissions, stands for the ownership permissions, and the owner is root in the group of root.

I have ssh'd into my server using:

`ssh root@server.com`

Once I login, it say's

`root@127.0.0.1:~#`

I have tried changing it's ownership, chmodding it, using vi to change permissions, trying to force it doesn't work either, how can I edit this damned file ! :(

When I try to use `sudo` it say's the command is not found, so I'm assuming that's because Thecus have stripped down the commands.

The output of `mount` without any arguments, I have noticed that the directory that I'm currently working in, is actually set to `ro`, is there a way I can edit this?

`/dev/cloop2 on /img/www type ext2 (ro,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl)`

Any help would be great! :)

Comment: Maybe the file system is mounted read-only. What is the output of `mount` (without any arguments)?

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to 'remount' it, but hey we'll see, I've edit my question with your question :) @rmartinjak

Comment: In that output, I have noticed `/dev/cloop2 on /img/www type ext2 (ro,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl)`, which obviously is the directory I'm using, and it's set to `ro`, is there a way to change this?

Comment: @rmartinjak did you have an idea sir? :)

Comment: I posted an answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mount -o remount,rw /img/www/`, if that is not possible, you can copy the contents to a place where you can modify them, unmount the original `/img/www/` and then symlink or "bind mount" the new location there.

Comment: I tried remounting it using your command, it said `mount: /img/www not mounted already, or bad option`, I also can't umount it because it's 'in use'

Comment: Surely there's a file somewhere, that initially sets up the 'ro' permissions to mount the /img/www/ directory?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're familiar with 'cloop', but from what I have just read, in wiki `It adds support for transparently decompressed, read-only block devices`

Comment: There's nothing under `/etc/fstab`, I have tried that too, I'm assumimg that this is because Thecus are using Cloop

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: `cp -a /img/www /srv; umount /img/www; mount --bind /srv/www /img/www` (instead of `/srv` you can use any other place you like)